# Sequelize.s include where ancestor column

Tags: join, associations, sequelize.js, where-clause

Sorry for my bad English, but I do not know how to better formulate the title.
Anyway I have the following 3 models

```
 const ModelAlpha = sequelize.define('tbl_A', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        field: 'a_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    }
});


const ModelBeta = sequelize.define('tbl_B', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        field: 'b_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    attributeB: {
        type: Sequelize.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
        field: 'b_attribute'
    }
});


const ModelCharlie = sequelize.define('tbl_C', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        field: 'c_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    attributeC: {
        type: Sequelize.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
        field: 'c_attribute'
    }
});
```

One ModelAlpha has one ModelBeta.
ModelAlpha has a foreign key column referencing the primary key of ModelBeta.
ModelAlpha can have many ModelCharlie
I am to trying to achieve the following

```
SELECT C.* FROM tbl_C
JOIN tbl_A ON tbl_A.a_id = C.fkey_a_id
JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_B.b_id = tbl_A.fkey_b_id
WHERE C.c_attribute = B.b_attribute
AND tbl_A.a_id = 123
```

So, in other words, all Charlies of the Alpha whose id is 123
and whose c_attribute is equal to b_attribute of the Beta

So far I have written something like the following,
but I am stuck as to what I am supposed to add to the where
clause.

```
   ModelAlpha.belongsTo(ModelBeta, {foreignKey: 'fkey_b_id', as: 'beta'});
   ModelAlpha.hasMany(ModelCharlie,{foreignKey: 'fkey_a_id', as : 'charlies'});

    ModelAlpha.find({
    where: {id: '123'},
    include: [
        {
            model: ModelBeta,
            as: 'beta',
            attributes: [],
        },
        {
            model: ModelCharlie,
            as: 'charlies',
            attributes:[],
            where: {
                attributeC: ......
            }
        }
    ],
    limit: 1
}).then(result => {
     //...

});
```

Has anyone come up with this situation before?
Thank you.